# Error while using gulp-angular-filesort

Tags: angularjs, gulp

While injecting my vendor and app scripts:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),   
    gInject = require('gulp-inject'),
    gDebug = require('gulp-debug'),   
    gAngularFileSort = require('gulp-angular-filesort'),
    series = require('stream-series')
    ;    

    var paths = {
        any: '**/*',
        src: 'src/',
        dist: 'dist/',
        distVendors: 'dist/vendors',
        distApp: 'dist/app'
    };


    gulp.task('injectDist', [], function(){
    var injectOptions = {
        relative:true
    };
    var target = gulp.src(paths.dist+'index.html');
    var vendorSources = gulp.src(paths.distVendors + "**/*.js");
    var appSources = gulp.src(paths.distApp + "/**/*.js");
    return target
        .pipe(gDebug())
        .pipe(
            gInject(series(vendorSources, appSources), injectOptions)
                .pipe(gAngularFileSort())
         )
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

Once launched this task I got next error:

[21:41:46] Starting 'injectDist'...

[21:41:46] gulp-debug: dist\index.html

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^

Error: Error in parsing: "index.html", Line 1: Unexpected token <

If remove ".pipe(gAngularFileSort()) no error occured.

Dont understand why gulp-angular-filesort played with index.html if src files only with .js extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 .pipe(
      gInject(series(vendorSources, appSources).pipe(gAngularFileSort()),injectOptions)
 )
```

i didn't use stream-series but with gulp.src worked well.